# Why variable A is not being copied to variable B?

Tags: flutter, dart, pointers, arraylist

I'm using two variables with the same value. Variable A is an initial variable and variable B is the one that I use to apply changes, so when I want to reset variable B I just assign A to it, the problem is each time I do it, the changes of B then applied to both. I have look in many places and these are the solutions I tried:

1. List.toList()

   ```
   _fields!.clear();
   _fields = _initFields!.toList();
   ```
2. Spread operator (...)

   ```
   _fields!.clear();
   _fields = [...?_initFields];
   ```

Also tried the ones below from this post: [Dart/Flutter – How to clone/copy a list](https://coflutter.com/dart-flutter-how-to-clone-copy-a-list/)

```
var newNumbers = List.from(numbers);
var newNumbers = List.generate(numbers.length, (index) => numbers[index]);
var newNumbers = List.of(numbers);
var newNumbers = List.unmodifiable(numbers);
```

Here the complete code:

```
import 'package:project/utilities/classes/filter_field.dart';

class FilterLogic {

  List<FilterField>? _initFields = [];
  List<FilterField>? _fields = [];
  bool? listComplete = false;

  void addField(FilterField? field) {

      _fields!.add(field!);

  }

  void addInitField(FilterField? field) {

    _initFields!.add(field!);

  }

  List<FilterField>? getFields() {

    return _fields;

  }

  void resetFieldsToOriginal() {

    _fields!.clear();
    _fields = [...?_initFields!];

  }

  void showFields() {

    print('_fields --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');

    _fields!.forEach((element) {
      if(element.checked == true) {
        print({ element.checked, element.field, element.filteredApplied, element.criteria, element.filteringOperators});
      }
    });

    print('_initFields --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');

    _initFields!.forEach((element) {
      if(element.checked == true) {
        print({ element.checked, element.field, element.filteredApplied, element.criteria, element.filteringOperators});
      }
    });

  }

}
```

Here is how I fill both variables:

```
filterCol.forEach((column) {
  String? filteredApplied;
  String? filteredCriteria = 'None';
  bool checked = false;

  filtersList.forEach((element) {
    if (column.field == element.field) {
      filteredApplied = element.operator;
      filteredCriteria = element.criteria;
      checked = true;
    }
  });

    FilterField field = FilterField(
      filteredApplied: filteredApplied,
      field: column.field,
      label: column.label,
      filteringOperators: column.filteringOperators,
      criteria: filteredCriteria,
      checked: checked == true ? true : false,
    );

  FilterField initField = FilterField(
    filteredApplied: filteredApplied,
    field: column.field,
    label: column.label,
    filteringOperators: column.filteringOperators,
    criteria: filteredCriteria,
    checked: checked == true ? true : false,
  );

  setState(() {

    filterLogic.addField(field);
    filterLogic.addInitField(initField);

  });
  
});
```

Here where I call the reset method:

```
DialogButton(
  width: 106.25,
  child: Text(
    "CANCEL",
    style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14, fontFamily: 'Chivo'),
  ),
  onPressed: () => {
    Navigator.of(context).pop(),
    setState(() {
    filterLogic.resetFieldsToOriginal();  // <-------------
  })
  },
  color: Color.fromRGBO(84, 84, 84, 1),
  radius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
),
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not enough just to copy the list cause your new list has references to the same `FilterField` instances. That means if you change any `FilterField` in the new list the same changes would be in the old one. So in your case, you need to make a so-called `deep` clone. You can create a method for that:

```
class FilterField {
   // ... other code
   FilterField CopyWith() {
      return new FilterField(...);
   }
}
```

and then you could something like that:

```
var newList = oldList.toList().map((item) => item.CopyWith()).toList();
```

and now you could change the lists separately.

But be aware that if `FilterField` has any other instances of classes that need to be changed you need to create new instances of those instances either. That's why it's called a deep clone.

Hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: I could resolve the issue iterating through every object and setting each non final variable to a default value. Your explanation was a great help to come to that solution.